# Filter a Javascript array to check specific value in all nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter an array in order to check if a specific value of all nested objects (I have items containing other items) matches my condition.

The following is working just fine, but I need to iterate the process until all matching elements are found.

```
// My filter
var itemsNumber = e.items.filter(function(superhero) {
    return superhero.group && superhero.group.items && superhero.group.items[0] && superhero.group.items[0].id === "1517" 


    /* I basically need to iterate the following process:

            || superhero.group && superhero.group.items && superhero.group.items[1] && superhero.group.items[1].id === "1517"

            || superhero.group && superhero.group.items && superhero.group.items[2] && superhero.group.items[2].id === "1517"

            || superhero.group && superhero.group.items && superhero.group.items[3] && superhero.group.items[3].id === "1517"

            || superhero.group && superhero.group.items && superhero.group.items[4] && superhero.group.items[4].id === "1517"

        ... And so on.

    */

});

 console.log(itemsNumber.length);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
return superhero.group &&
       superhero.group.items &&
       superhero.group.items.some(({id}) => id === "1517");
```

or if you need that in ES5:

```
return superhero.group &&
       superhero.group.items &&
       superhero.group.items.some(function(item) {
        return item.id === "1517";
       });
```

`some` calls its callback once for each entry in the array and either returns `true` the first time the callback returns a truthy¹ value, or returns `false` if the callback never returns a truthy value (including if there were no entries in the array at all). That is, it checks if "some" (really, "any') item in the array matches the predicate expressed by the callback.

Here's an example (in ES2015+) for both when the condition is true and when it's false:

```js
function check(superhero) {
    return superhero.group &&
           superhero.group.items &&
           superhero.group.items.some(({id}) => id === "1517");
}

function test(superhero, expect) {
    const result = check(superhero);
    console.log(`Checking ${JSON.stringify(superhero)}: ${result} <= ${!result === !expect ? "OK" : "ERROR"}`);
}

test({group: {items: [{id: "1"}, {id: "1517"}, {id: "9999"}]}}, true);
test({group: {items: [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "3"}]}}, false);
```

---

¹ "truthy value" - a "truthy" value is any value that isn't "falsy." A *falsy* value is a value that evaluates to `false` when used as a condition (such as `if (x)`). The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I just tried your code, unfortunately it seems to miss some items while counting theirs length. I guess I need to chek "every" items contained in "every" group.

Comment: @Antony - I'm not sure what you mean by "every group." There's only one group shown in your code (which has a property called `items`, which is an array).

Comment: @Antony This answer is sound based on what you provided, could some group item `id` values in your data be actual integers not strings? i.e. does using loose equality ( `id == "1517"`) catch those missed items?

Comment: On second look at the commented example, we may have overlooked the or op (`||`) in which case try using [.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `.every`.

Comment: @David `.some` actually did the trick. Thanks you all for your help!

Comment: @Antony - I've fixed the answer now. Sorry about that. It's weird, because I remember thinking "It's odd to check that they all have the same ``id`." I should have double-checked the question when I thought that.